# How do I dismiss other UIPopoverControllers when presenting a new one?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

If I have several buttons that launches the same popovers, how can I dismiss the an already visible popover before displaying the new one?

I have a local variable self.popover that is set to the current popovercontroller; i check this popover variable to see if it is visible; if it is visible then I dismiss it and then present the new one, but the new one doesnt become visible until I touch it twice.

Comment: As an FYI, Xcode is a development tool, not a language or framework.  It doesn't really have anything to do with your recent questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dismissing the existing popover using [myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO]

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that by default your popover dismisses itself any time a touch occurs outside the popover itself; the touch event itself never gets propagated to the button as it "belongs" to the UIPopoverController. Once this occurs, you have to touch the button again to re-pop.

The best fix would be to retain a pointer to the UIPopoverController, and send an NSArray of the buttons you wish to dismiss/pop popovers from to the controller.

Then in the handler for each of these, check whether a popover is present. If so, dismiss it, and pop the popover for the button.